# db.eval not working inside a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have called `eval()` function inside a another function.

It is not working.

**Question:** How do I calling a JavaScript function inside?

```
db.check.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
    var first='Press Hydralic';
    var second=doc.ESCN;
    var count='';
    count=db.eval("echoFunction(first,second)");
    console.log(first,second,count);
})
```

Comment: You might describe 'not working' in more detail - does it throw an error or do you just get a result different than what you expect?

Comment: {
 "message" : "MongoError: ReferenceError: first is not defined : @:1:15 ",
 "stack" : "script:5:10" +
              "script:1:19",
 "code" : 139
} thats the error its showing